# What is entityName parameter in save method?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have started learning Hibernate and have a basic question.

What is the difference between `save(String entityName, Object object)` and `save(Object object)` in the `org.hibernate.Session` class. 
Basically I want to know what the `entityName` parameter is in this overloaded method.
I tried to look at the API but didn't glean much from there.

Answer (score 2):

It's a logical name for an entity intended to match the same entity-name in a mapping file.  It defaults to the class name for the current entity, but if you provide your own value, then you can use the same class with multiple different mapping files.

See http://www.martinahrer.at/2008/04/09/55/  and  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html  and http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels  and http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/xml.html (search for "entity-name" in each case).

Answer (score 0):

It's Hibernate Object Identifier. It's not recommended to use this in save() method.
please refer to http://www.hibernate-training-guide.com/object-identifiers.html

Comment: It's not the identifier.  It's a logical name for a mapped entity - matches the entity name in a mapping file :)